# Series problems forloop

Tags: c#, for-loop, fibonacci

i have a problem in my series number that will output the 1,2,4,7,11 and etc. i have my forloop that handle the 0,1,2,3,4,5 but im having trouble to progress the 1,2,4,7,11 output please help me this is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            for (int v = 0; v <= 5; v++)
            {
                for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
                {
                    int c = v + x;


                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();



        }

    }       
}
```

Comment: I upvoted this question to balance the previous downvote. I think this question is legitimate.

Comment: But what is the aim of your loop ? What result are you expecting ?

Comment: i want the result to be 1 ,2 ,4 ,7 ,11.
that my first loop will be 0,1,2,3,4,5 then the 2nd is to sum it should be 1+0=1, 1+1=2 ,2+2=4, 4+3=7 like that.

Comment: @CoderShei
 your code will execute the inner loop (x=1, x=2, x=3, etc... and then v=1,v=2, etc... so you will have c=1, c=2,c=3,etc...)
Btw : On google, type "C# fibonacci" and click on "Feel lucky"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok try this...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int c = 1;
        for (int v = 0; v <= 5; v++)
        {
            c = c + v;
            Console.Write("{0} ", c);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
     }
 }
```

I hope it will help you...

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var iterations = 50;
            var result = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                result += i;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to control number to calculate from console not by code:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to calculate: ");
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Fib(0, 1, 1, num);
    }   

    public static void Fib(int i, int j, int count, int num)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        if (count < num) Fib(j, i+j, count+1, num);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
int x = 1;

        for (int v = 0; v <= 5; v++)
        {
            int c = x + v;
            x = c;
            Console.Write(c);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: `for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++) Console.Write(n * (n + 1) / 2 + 1 + " ");`

Answer (score 0):

It seems something like this :

```
var f1 = 0;
var f2 = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{

    Console.WriteLine(f1);

    f1 = f2;
    f2 = f2 + i;
}
```

Output :

> 0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 11

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

`int i=1;
    int j=0;
    while(i<50)
    {
        i+=j;
        j+=1;
        Console.Writeln(i)
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I hope , it should be solve the problem

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace While_loop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 1;
            Console.WriteLine(i);

            while (i < 10)
            {
                        for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++)
                  {
                        i = i + j;
                        Console.WriteLine(i);  
                  }
                i++;
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```